# C - Haversine formula slightly off

Tags: c, haversine

My output seems to be slightly off when calculating the distance between two lat/lon coordinates and I can't seem to work out why. Below is my code (implementation of Haversine formula)

```
float calcDistance(double latHome, double lonHome, double latDest, double lonDest) {

    double pi = 3.141592653589793;
    int R = 6371; //Radius of the Earth
    latHome = (pi/180)*(latHome);
    latDest = (pi/180)*(latDest);
    double differenceLon = (pi/180)*(lonDest - lonHome);
    double differenceLat = (pi/180)*(latDest - latHome);
    double a = sin(differenceLat/2) * sin(differenceLat/2) + 
    cos(latHome) * cos(latDest) * 
    sin(differenceLon/2) * sin(differenceLon/2);
    double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
    double distance = R * c;
    printf("%f\n", distance);
    return distance;
}
```

Input: 38.898556 -77.037852 38.897147 -77.043934

Output: 0.526339

Supposed to get 0.5492

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of input, actual output, and the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, added example

Comment: The code is correct (syntactically), make sure you use the "right" formula. There is no funky truncation going on

Comment: The formula itself looks wrong to me. Why are you using arctangent? The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#The_haversine_formula) is in terms of arcsin(sqrt(a)) for your variable a.

Comment: What is the output unit? Miles? Meters? Rods? Parsecs?

Comment: Have you done the calculation manually on a calculator and compared all the intermediate values in that with the intermediate values in your function?  Have you printed out the inputs to ensure that they are what you expect?  How do you know the answer is supposed to be what you say it should be?

Comment: Note: `2*atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));` has only a single quadrant answer.  Might as well use `2*asin(sqrt(a))` to maintain precision.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of (and if fixed gives the expected result) is the fact that you overwrite the local parameters `latHome` and `latDest` (but probably should use the original ones when calculating `differenceLon` and `differenceLat` above `a`). Use a different name for those, like `latHomeTmp`, then calculate `a` with the new ones, and it will work, like:

```
double latHomeTmp = (pi/180)*(latHome);
double latDestTmp = (pi/180)*(latDest);
double a = sin(differenceLat/2.) * sin(differenceLat/2.) + 
           cos(latHomeTmp) * cos(latDestTmp) * 
           sin(differenceLon/2.) * sin(differenceLon/2.);
```

In general it is a good idea to keep the parameters passed to a function immutable, to avoid situations like this one (of course, not a set in stone rule, but I usually obey it).

Comment: Yes, the problem was that the latitudes were converted from degrees to radians, and then the difference between the latitudes (already in radians) was converted from degrees to radians again. So the problem could also be fixed by removing the `(pi/180)` from the latitude difference calculation.